# Difference between two codes

Tags: javascript, syntax

Hei guys, i'm sorry for this title, but i can't think how to explain my problem.

I want know why this two codes (for me is the same thing), returns different results:

```js
var name  = 'NAME';
var rules = [
  { name: 'NAME_RULES' }
];

var x = [].push(rules.map(function(rule){
  return rule.name;
}));

document.body.innerHTML = x;
```

And:

```js
var name  = 'NAME';
var rules = [
  { name: 'NAME_RULES' }
];

var x = [];
y = rules.map(function(rule){
  return rule.name;
});
x.push(y);

console.log(x);
```

I want achieve the same result from the first snnipet.

Thanks.

Comment: why not use the second part?

Comment: `[].push` just modifies the array, without returning it

Comment: Check documentation for `push`, and you'll see that it has no return value.

Comment: `push()` returns the length of the array (after pushing), not the array itself.  The array is modified in-place.

Comment: `var x = [rules.map(r=>r.name)];` is same

Comment: Hei guys, thanks for all answers! <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[].push` returns the new length of the array not the modified array

```
var x = [rules.map(function(rule){
  return rule.name;
})];
```

You can just create the array with that value in it.